# Customize Google Charts Gantt tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, jsapi

I've tried to customize the tooltip for the Gantt Google Chart and it does not seem to apply

I've added :

```
 data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```

and options

```
tooltip: {isHtml: true},
legend: 'none'
```

But it does not seem to work.
Below it's a fiddle with the implementation as provided by Google and adapted by me as described above.
Any idea why it does not work?

https://jsfiddle.net/uped4teh/1/

Answer (score 8):

I'm working with the same chart and I have several problems... The  Html tooltip feature is not available for google gantt chart, you can read about it in the section "Supported charts" in the link that I copy below...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Good Lucky

Let me know if my answer helped you

Answer (score 2):

Google Chart Gantt HTML tooltips is not available yet,

HTML tooltips are currently supported for the following chart types:
AreaChart, BarChart, CalendarChart, CandlestickChart, ColumnChart, ComboChart, LineChart, PieChart, Sankey Diagrams, ScatterChart, Timeline.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#supported-charts

Answer (score 0):

in google documentation we have **"Google Charts automatically creates tooltips for all core charts"**
that means your package should be corechart like
**google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});**
and not as yours
**google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});**
custom tooltip is not support by gannt chart, change for timeline to use corechart package